# Можно ли повесить onchange для двух событий (выбор select + нажатие на кнопку)?

Tags: javascript

Задача такая что если пользователь не выбрал select тогда нужно скрыть блок (это я сделал так):

в style.css

```
#hour {
display: none;
}
```

в script

```
function show() {
document.getElementById('hour').style.display = "block";
}
```

в html

```
<SELECT name='abcd' onchange="show(this.value)"><OPTION selectedvalue=0>00<OPTION value=1>01<OPTION value=2>02<OPTION value=3>
03</OPTION></select>
```

Теперь когда пользователь выбирает любой пункт из select, то скрытые блоки показываются.
Но мне нужно чтобы блоки показывались только если пользователь выбрал select + нажал на кнопку "расчёт". А пока не нажал на кнопку, то чтобы блоки по прежнему были скрыты. Т.е. нужно чтобы выполнились два условия для отображения. Выбран любой value select + нажалась кнопка. Как должен выглядеть код функции для такой задачи?
Кнопка имеет такой вид:

```
<INPUT onclick=result(this.form) type=button value="Рассчитать" "document.location.reload()">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function abcdChange(select) {
  select.classList.add("user-selected");
}

function buttonClick() {
  var select = document.querySelector("select[name='abcd']");
  if (select && select.classList.contains("user-selected"))
    document.getElementById('hour').style.display = "block";
}

<SELECT name='abcd' onchange="abcdChange(this)">
  <OPTION selectedvalue=0>00</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=1>01</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=2>02</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=3>03</OPTION>
</select>

<INPUT onclick="buttonClick()" type=button value="Рассчитать">
```

Comment: @3vgeny Я совершенно не понимаю, о чем Вы говорите.